# JavaScript simple error

Tags: javascript

I'm having an error in my JavaScript program. Check it out:

HTML:

```
<form class="form-inline">
    <input class="form-control" id="present" placeholder="Introduza algo">");
</form>

<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="apresentar()">Result</button>

</div>
<div id="result">
</div>
```

JS:

```
function apresentar (){
    var b = document.getElementById("present").value;
    var c = document.getElementById("result");
    var a = c + b;
    c.innerHTML = a;

};
```

I want to input some text and this text will be concatenated with the earlier text I introduced.

Comment: `var a = c.innerHTML + b;`

Comment: You're concatenating a string with an object and then you wish to change the innerHTML of some object with that?

Comment: Why call an error "simple" if you are unable to solve it? Unless it's not a question but meant as some sort of riddle.

Comment: Try `var a = c.innerHTML + b` instead..

Answer (score 0):

You are adding a DOM element to text. Make this change:

```
function apresentar (){
    var b = document.getElementById("present").value;
    var c = document.getElementById("result");
    c.innerHTML += b;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have some invalid HTML.

After fixing it, it should look like this:

```
<form class="form-inline">
    <input class="form-control" id="present" placeholder="Introduza algo"/>
</form>

<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="apresentar()">Result</button>


<div id="result"></div>
```

Make sure you close all your tags correctly (such as `input`), and you have some closing `divs` that are not in place unless you're missing some code.

Then, as mentioned by the comments above, your function should look like this, after using `c.innerHTML`:

```
function apresentar(){
    var b = document.getElementById("present").value;
    var c = document.getElementById("result");
    var a = c.innerHTML + b;

    c.innerHTML = a;

};
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hgLn02zz/)